# Jupyter Notebook isn't printing output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ide

I have tried reconnecting to the kernel and also restarting the kernel but it has refused to print any output. Here's a picture that gives further details: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqhLb.png)

I just want it to print an output that's all

Comment: You've cut off the top of your code cell that gives the status of it? This is partly why images are highly discouraged here and full descriptions of the situation. For example, just given the screenshot we cannot tell if the cell you show has even been run yet or it it stuck on something above. A full description of the situation in the text would be important. **More importantly, why are you using the experimental JupyterLite?** See 'Status' [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and the highlighted 'Experimental' [here](https://jupyter.org/try). It is common for JupyterLite...

Comment: <continued> to hang if the status of it initializing itself is not allowed to complete fully, and get to not busy, at start up of the kernel **before attempting to run code**. Is that what is happening here? (We cannot tell based on your lackluster post so far.) If so, or if what I'm asking isn't making sense, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-lab-not-executing-python-code/20998/3?u=fomightez) for more about this. Finally, and getting back to why I really want to know why you are using JupyterLite, you may be exceeding the limited abilities of your browser to run demanding ...

Comment: <continued> computational steps. I see in the very limited code visible in your post screenshot `sklearn` and terms 'hperparameter', 'fit', and PCA. All indicative of maybe machine language application being attempted? In the future read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One good idea is to look at other examples of recent, well-scoring questions on this site and compare the post to yours. In the guide play close attention to parts about writing a title and 'Help others reproduce the problem'. And relevant tags because Jupyter Notebooks ...

Comment: <continued> can run a lot of languages and no where do you mention the language of the code you are using. Did you try running this directly in [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/) **so you are sure Jupyter Notebook is the problem** as your title and tags imply?

Comment: I happen to have scikit-learn already installed in temporary sessions you can get [by clicking here for a full Python kernel served via the MyBinder service](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb). That session will give you Python kernel that is a full, typical Python kernel and not the limited Pyodide. However, the computational power of that session is limited and so it still may not be able to run your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.